# Tripadvisor web scraping using python

Tags: python

i am using the following code to extract reviews from a url using python, but the exported csv doesnt have all reviews in a column. Instead, it exports data in different columns.
Do i have to add any code to the existing one?

```
import requests
from unidecode import unidecode
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g295424-d1735662-Reviews-
Winchester_Grand_Hotel_Apartments-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai/"
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

resultsoup = soup.find_all("p", {"class" : "partial_entry"})

with open('testreview.csv', 'w') as fid:
   for review in resultsoup:
      review_list = review.get_text()
      fid.write(unidecode(review_list))
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `csv.writer` for csv files (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All you need is probably to add a new line character ('\n') to the line you're writing to file.

All you need is probably to add a new line character ('\n') to the line you're writing to file.

```
with open('testreview.csv', 'w') as fid: 
    for review in resultsoup: 
        review_list = review.get_text()
        fid.write(unidecode(review_list+'\n'))
```